# Does stack-unwinding deallocate memory allocated on heap?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, exception

If I have the following:

```
try{
    int* i = new int(5);
    //exception thrown here
}
catch(const exception& e){
    //Do I need to delete the heap allocation here?
}
```

A heap allocation is made shortly before an exception is thrown, as part of the stack-unwinding would that heap memory get reclaimed? or would there be a memory leak and I would be expected to handle this within the `catch()` statement?

Comment: You'll have a memory leak. You need to delete memory in `catch` clause.

Comment: However, if you make it `unique_ptr<int> i{new int(5)};`, then memory will in fact be deallocated during stack unwinding, by `unique_ptr`'s destructor. That's the main point of smart pointers.

Comment: Only if you say it should, like by properly using RAII or adding the manual steps. Igor showed one way to do it with RAII.

Answer (score 4):

No, only destructors will be called during stack unwinding, there will be no "manual frees" or something like this. You `int` will leak. To avoid such problems use RAII, for example you could use `std::vector<int>` instead of raw C-style arrays or `std::unique_pointer` for your example. It is in general considered good practice to avoid "naked" `new`s and only use it in the implementation of resource handlers like `std::vector` of `std::unique_pointer`. The problem you described is one of the bigger reasons for that.

Answer (score 0):

Stack unwinding or auto-docking  produce abandon object, means which is not having any reference in stack .Then that abandon object will be clean by GC and will revert back memory to OS in JAVA.
BUT in C++ need to take care about memory management, in this case it will leak memory , you will have to handle explicitly.
this is my point of view :

```
delete i;         
  system("PAUSE");
```

Better if you can go to here..
[**C ++ common memory leak problem**](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c++_memory_problems.html)

Comment: What do you mean by "you can try with this `int a = new int[5];`"? Even if we assume you meant `int *a`, this will at beast create an even larger memory leak.

Comment: Hi @jogojapan , I had to put (int *a) only actually .And That's why i have given that Link to get some help.